# Expectation of throws of fair coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Suppose we are throwing fair coin infinitely many times. I need to find expectation of obtaining three heads in the row (HHH).

I think we have to use Markov's chains, but I'm not sure how to define states...